# How can i select an html element based on type and not hierarchy using only CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm wondering if it is possible to target the last element of a particular type in CSS, knowing that there is no hierarchy so I can't use: the last-child CSS selector.

I want to apply a red font color to the last `<p>` tag following each `<h1>` tag.

The HTML is composed of  one `<h1>` tag followed by multiple (number may vary) `<p>` tags, as shown in the code below

I want to do this only with CSS! (no JS or SCSS ...)

```
<body>
<h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>

<h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>

<h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
```

I tried :

```
h1 ~ p:last-of-type {
      color: red;
    }
```

but then it only selects the very last p, which is logical and understandable

I also tried this :

```
h1 ~ p:nth-last-of-type(3n) {
      color: blue;
    }
```

it works only when I have 3 'p' tags in each 'h1' tag

Comment: what you want output , can you add image output also

Comment: Hi, MAYUR SANCHETI, 

I just want to apply a red font color to the last p element following each h1 tag, no images are needed for my case!

Comment: is it like below answer

Comment: No, with CSS you cannot do that. You would need a `previous sibling selector` which does not exist in CSS. With the current HTML structure you cannot do it with just CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```css
  p:has(+ h1), h1 ~ p:last-of-type {
      color: red;      
    }
```

```html
<body>
<h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>

<h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>

<h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
<p>ppppp</p>
```

- **p:has(+ h1)** targets a p that has a h1 after it
- **h1 ~ p:last-of-type**, as you said, targets the last one

EDIT: As Mihai pointed out, this is not a good idea because of browser compatibility. We need a previous sibling selector, which is not here yet...

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-has not really a good idea to use a selector that's not supported by all browsers ( especially not firefox )

Comment: i think this is correct ,

Comment: why this is not working for me ..

Answer (score 1):

you can try putting every section in a div like this

```
<div>
  <h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
  <p>ppppp</p>
  <p>ppppp</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
  <p>ppppp</p>
  <p>ppppp</p>
  <p>ppppp</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>hhhhhhhhh</h1>
  <p>ppppp</p>
  <p>ppppp</p>
  <p>ppppp</p>
  <p>ppppp</p>
</div>
```

and css like this

```
h1 ~ p:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

and that should work